# How do you insert space between current code line and next line?

Tags: notepad++, editor, enter

I am using Notepad ++ and when I press "Enter" it inserts a new line. My current situation is that my line contains 100+ characters and I want to put some characters under without having to scroll all the way to the right.

Not sure if I am making sense, but it basically looks like this:

line 54: //code

***space**: // line 54 code

***space**: // line 54 code

line 55: //code

I tried split line, but that didn't do anything for me (CTRL + I).

Comment: When you say `characters under`, do you mean at the end of the same line? If so, if you are at the beginning of line 54 (or anywhere on the same line, technically), pressing the `end` key will position the cursor to the end of the same line without having to scroll.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52844685/edit) and add some sample lines and expected result. And format properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Word wrap (View > Word wrap) turned on? That makes lines wrap nicely onto one page so you don't have to scroll across long lines.